# I have 2 json files where i need to convert into java and perform operation like deletion based on the unique key

Tags: java

This is my one json file as employee-list.json

```
[
  {
    "organizationId": 1,
    "organizationName": "Dell",
    "departments": [
      {
        "departmentId": 1,
        "departmentName": "ADM",
        "employees": [
          {
            "employeeId": 101,
            "employeeName": "Ramesh"
          },
          {
            "employeeId": 105,
            "employeeName": "Srikanth"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "departmentId": 2,
        "departmentName": "BFSI",
        "employees": [
          {
            "employeeId": 102,
            "employeeName": "Suresh"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

second file is delete.json

```
[
  {
    "organizationId": 1,
    "organizationName": "dell",
    "departments": [
      {
        "departmentId": 1,
        "departmentName": "ADM",
        "employees": [         
          {
            "employeeId": 105,
            "employeeName": "Srikanth"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "departmentId": 2,
        "departmentName": "BFSI",
        "employees": [
          {
            "employeeId": 102,
            "employeeName": "Suresh"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to remove delete.json file data from employee-list.json data and store the remaining data into another output .json which looks as below

```
[
  {
    "organizationId": 1,
    "organizationName": "dell",
    "departments": [
      {
        "departmentId": 1,
        "departmentName": "ADM",
        "employees": [
          {
            "employeeId": 101,
            "employeeName": "Ramesh"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Can anyone help me in coding this in java using MAPS...?
Inside organisation we have set of departments ,inside departments we have set of employees

Comment: SO is _not_ a coding service ...

Answer (score 0):

Use `org.json` library.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(/*JSONArray*/);
String get = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("key");
```

---

1. Create three JSONArrays (emp-list, delete and output).
2. Iterate through emp-list and write the content into output.
3. Check for the similar values in the delete JSONArray (While iterating).
4. Skip adding if the value matches.
5. Finally you'll end up with a filtered `JSONArray`.
6. Use `toString()` method and save the String to a file.

---

- [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20140107) - [jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/json/json/20140107/json-20140107.jar)
- [Documentation](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.json/json/20141113)

Comment: In what way is this answer related to the question (besides dealing with JSON)? And who upvoted this?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Wanted to give the OP a heads up, on how to start. I didn't wanted to write the whole code for him. Edited now please read.